# Inheritance in Java simple clarification

Tags: java, inheritance

So, I have this:

```
public class A {

    public int a = 0;
    public void m(){
        System.out.println("A"+a);
    }
}
```

And this:

```
public class B extends A {

    public int a = 5 ;
    public void m (){
        System.out.println("B"+a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A oa = new A();
        B ob = new B();
        A oab = ob;
        oa.m();
        ob.m();
        oab.m();

        System.out.println("AA"+oa.a);
        System.out.println("BB"+ob.a);
        System.out.println("AB"+oab.a);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A0
B5
B5
AA0
BB5
AB0
```

---

I don't understand why **oab.m();** output is **B5** instead of **A0**. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 9):

That's the whole point of polymorphism. The concrete type of `oab` is `B` (since the object was created with `new B()`). So the method `B.m()` is called.

Look at the Animal example in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29 to understand why it's useful. When you have an animal, and this animal is a Cat, you expect it to say "Meow!" when you make it talk.

Comment: The method `m()` is overridden in `class B`. Both `class A` and `class B` have the same method signature for `m()`. It is the most specific method that is called and as `oab` is an instance of `class B`, it is `b.m()` that is called. The variable `oab` is simply being referenced as type `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
B ob = new B();
A oab = ob;
```

Similar as

```
A oab=new B();
```

`I don't understand why oab.m(); output is B5 instead of A0`

Because you creating object of `B` and referencing it to A so `m()` is being inherited and that's why `B's version` of `m()`is being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
A oa = new A();
B ob = new B();
A oab = ob;
```

From the code above ob is an instance of class B. It can be stored in a variable of class A as A extends B. But as the stored Object instance is of B and hence it is not aware of A's m() function.
Hence the out put is  `B5`

Comment: `oab` is aware of the fact that that there is a function `void m()`, since class A has that function defined. However, since the implementation of the function is overridden in class B, which is the real type of the object, it calls the implementation of `void m()` in class B.

Comment: that is it nhahtdh. What puzzled me most was that i've put the method **void m()** in class A as comment, and then **oab** stopped beind aware of **void m()**. that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In inheritance actual method invocation depends on the type of the actual object and not on the type of the reference.

```
 B ob = new B();
 A oab = ob;
```

Here `oab` is a reference variable of type `A` but it is pointing to object of type `B` i.e. `ob` so at runtime `oab.m()` will invoke overridden `m()` method from class `B`

Comment: @Faico: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is something like late binding (polymorphism). It means that **code of method** is not linked while compilation time (early binding), but while runtime. While invoking `oab.m();` JVM is checking actual type (class) of object from `aob` reference (in your case `B`) and based on that info invoking code of method from that class. That is why `oab.m();` returns `B5`.

You also need to know that late binding works only for methods, not fields. For fields value will be determined by reference type, so `oab.a` will return `0` not `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you had the following:

```
public class C extends A {

public int a = 7 ;
public void m (){
    System.out.println("C"+a);
}
```

Now if you had this in your Main method...

```
C oc = new C();
A oac = oc;
oac.m();
```

...you would want that last call to output the stuff that is specific for the class C.

The point is that **B is an A**, and **C is an A**, but each of them have more specific versions of the values that an A contains, and when you ask for those data, the specific versions of them should be returned.

Now you can do this:

```
// Get an instance of B or C, but you don't
// care which - could be either:
A someVersionOfA = getAnInstanceOfA(); 

// This works no matter if you've got an instance
// of B or C, but the result should vary accordingly:
someVersionOfA.m();
```

As someone else mentioned, think of **A** as "Animal", **B** as "cat", and **C** as "Dog". If **m()** means "Make some noise", then calling m() should result in "Meow" or "Woof!" depending on on the instance *getAnInstanceOfA()* returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have just copied the internal address of B to A one, and replacing it.

B inherit from A, so no compilation problem.

Finally, the reference to A is destroyed, it is now a copy of reference to B